# Installing Silverstripe 3.1 on subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, silverstripe

First time asking a question here but I'm really stuck.
Basically I'm trying to install a Silverstripe 3.1 cms on a subdomain as a development site, on my main domain I already have a Silverstripe 2.4 site running.

The first thing that comes up is this error, "development" is the subdomain folder.

***Warning: require_once(framework/dev/install/DatabaseConfigurationHelper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/usr/public_html/subdomain/framework/dev/install/install.php5 on line 39***

I check if the file is there and it is, then I check if the filepath is wrong because the file that is calling require_once has a full path from home/ but that can't be it because I've been able to install Silverstripe on my localhost.

I google redirecting (I've had no experience with it before) and find stuff on htaccess related to Silverstripe but none were problems that I was having, i.e. there are .htaccess files in main directory and subdomain. Not too sure if they're conflicting but I have tried RewriteEngine Off on my subdomain. I mostly leave the default Silverstripe .htaccess files as they are.

Even declaring different suPHP_ConfigPath's i.e.
main website: home/usr/public_html/
subdomain: home/usr/public_html/subdomain

At this point I look back at the error and try hacking the require_once filepath, changing it to 
**$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/framework/dev/install/DatabaseConfigurationHelper.php**

It mostly works but the requirements check page is void of css and any fails to GET any images

I am able to check all the requirements though passing everything but the File Permissions check:
**"Does the webserver know where files are stored?"** failed. Showing me the filepath it tried being the absolute path of a file prepended with the path to the subdomain. Looking at the code my hack was never intended to work.

Did I miss something? I'm not very knowledgeable with servers but I've done everything I can think of, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Possibly you want to setup a VirtualHost with Apache: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanks for your suggestion but I think it was meant for addon domains? I only wanted a subdomain for testing purposes.

What I ended up doing was to avoid installing Silverstripe on the server and instead install it on my laptop and then upload that to the server. It worked fine after copying the appropriate database and fixing Silverstripe's BaseURL to '/'